# Parsing reddit json into Python array and print items from array

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, reddit

This is my first couple of weeks coding; apologies for a basic question.

I've managed to parse the 'WorldNews' subreddit json, identify the individual children (24 of them as I write) and grab the titles of each news item. I'm now trying to create an array from these news titles. The code below does print the fifth title ([4]) to command line every 2-3 attempts (otherwise provides the error below). It will also not print more than one title at a time (for example if I try[2,3,4] I will continuously get the same error).

The error I get when doesn't compile:

```
in <module> Children = theJSON["data"]["children"] KeyError: 'data'
```

My script:

```
import requests 
import json


r = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/.json')
theJSON = json.loads(r.text)
Children = theJSON["data"]["children"]

News_list = []

for post in Children:
    News_list.append (post["data"]["title"])

print News_list [4]
```

Comment: theJSON doesn't have a key 'data'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll probably want to post a [mcve] in the future, as it helps people know where the problem is, and other things, thanks!

Comment: You can simply call `theJson = r.json()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution with the help of [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072846/eric). The issue here was in fact not related to the key, parsing or presentation of the dict or array. When requesting a Url from reddit and attempting to print the json string output we encounter an HTTP Error 429. Fixing this is simple. The answer was found on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/2yac4j/python_consistently_getting_429_errors_following/) redditdev thread.

Solution: by adding an identifier for the device requesting the Url ('User-agent' in header) it runs smoothly and works every time.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews.json', headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome'})

theJSON = json.loads(r.text)
print theJSON
```

Comment: Wacky, I could not reproduce after making the request hundreds of times in quick succession without this header.

Comment: You really should not try to pretend your script is Chrome; doing so is against [the API rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules) and will get you banned with prejudice.  You *should* use a custom user agent that identifies your script, and ideally your username, so the operations folks can separate out your client from others.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the payload you got didn't have a `data` key in it, for whatever reason. I don't know about Reddit's JSON API; I tested the request and saw that you were using the correct keys. The fact that you say your code works every few times tells me that you're getting a different response between requests. I can't reproduce it, I tried making the request over and over and checking for the correct response. If I had to guess why you'd get something different I'd say it'd have to be either rate limiting or a temporary 503 (Reddit having issues.)

You can guard against this by either catching the `KeyError` or using the `.get` method of dictionaries.

Catching `KeyError`:

```
try:
    Children = theJSON["data"]["children"]
except KeyError:
    print 'bad payload'
    return
```

Using `.get`:

```
Children = theJSON.get("data", {}).get("children")
if not Children:
    print 'bad payload'
    return
```

Comment: Problem is not in the post, it's in theJSON